# Get path of the process dynamically - TIBCO - BusinessWorks

Tags: tibco, businessworks

I am developing a process that will read and send an image in an e-mail.
This image is a folder within this process.

**The problem is: how do I get the path where the process is running?**

Something like a 
`'Server.MapPath'`
 that returns the image path in the File System.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TIBCO - BusinessWorks - Get path of the process dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111879/tibco-businessworks-get-path-of-the-process-dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

Did you get a chance to try my answer over at [TIBCommunity](http://www.tibcommunity.com/message/35856#35856)?

```
absPath = com.tibco.pe.core.Engine.getRepoAgent().getAbsoluteURIFromProjectRelativeURI(relativePath);
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. If I start using too much Java code in my projects I'll be forcing a situation that is not the purpose of the IDE TIBCO Design.

I discovered that there is an activity SOAP "Retrieve-Resources" that can perform what I need.
So this way i can get more coherence with the best practices in application development WebService.

Yes, i tried use your solution. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to drag-and-drop the image on the text field? Works surprisingly often in Tibco BW.